# SMS integration in yii

Tags: yii

I am trying to integrate SMS in my web application. I added the code in my last line of function:

```
header("Location:http://www.bulksmsservice.co.in");
```

But its not redirecting to that site. (Function is in model page)

Comment: You can use: `$this->redirect("http://www.bulksmsservice.co.in")`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the PHP Command header, be sure there is no output before you call it. To do it in the Yii view file is too late. But to do this in the Yii Controller is not a good Practice. Better would be $this->redirect() or in the view File use Javascript Code:

```
<script>
    window.location ='http://www.bulksmsservice.co.in';
</script>
```

Comment: i tried it.But its not working. It is unable to add <script> in my function(my function is in model page)

Comment: you should place the code in the view File. Can you paste the code her?

Comment: now its working but when i trying to send multiple messages,only the last one is send

Comment: you have to post a little bit more code, otherwise i'm "blind"

Answer (score 0):

i added my function sendbulk in controller and replace code with below

```
 function sendbulk($num,$msg)
 {
    $link = "http://www.bulksmsservice.co.in/api/sentsms.php?username=****&api_password=*******&to=".$no."&priority=2&sender=******&message=".$msg. "&unicode=1";
   $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => 1
       )
            )
    );
    file_get_contents($link, 0, $ctx);
  }
```

Now it's working perfectly for single messages and multiple messages :)